# Black/silent video with specific duration with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate video files that follow a "prototype" file as much as possible (frame rate, dimensions, container format, codecs, etc.) but show a black screen with silent audio. Here's one command line that works fine, and produces a 3-second-long file:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=3840x2160:r=25/1 -c:v h264 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=mono:r=48000 -c:a pcm_s16be -t 3 out.mov
```

Sometimes, the prototype file has codecs that ffmpeg can read but not write, like `pcm_bluray`. So instead of trying to use the same codec as the prototype, I omit this parameter and let ffmpeg pick a default:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=3840x2160:r=25/1 -c:v h264 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=mono:r=48000 -t 3 out.mov
```

To my surprise, I get a file that's 3.022s long. What's interesting is that both the streams are 3.0s long, but container duration is longer:

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",

            "time_base": "1/12800",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 38400,
            "duration": "3.000000",

            "nb_frames": "75",
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",

            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 144000,
            "duration": "3.000000",
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "3.022000",
    }
}
```

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a PCM codec. The default codec is AAC, which has a [priming sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42415886) that format in ffprobe accounts for, but stream won't, since the demuxer will have discarded it before sending it to the decoder for analysis.

P.S. your syntax is wrong - it should be `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=3840x2160:r=25/1 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=mono:r=48000 -c:v h264 -c:a pcm_s16be -t 3 out.mov`

Options before an input are applied to the input. You've gotten away with it because `-c:v h264` sets the video decoder for the following input. However, since it is an audio-only input, the effect is inert. And the default codec for MOV happens to be H264, so the outcome is what you desired.

Comment: Ouch. Thank you for pointing out the argument-order problem.

Comment: So if I play the file out, it will still play for 3.0s, correct? So if I want an accurate duration for a file with AAC streams, do I need to sum up the durations and start times of individual streams instead of relying on the container?

Comment: Which file? The one with AAC or PCM?

Comment: MOV with AAC. With PCM, all durations agree, so there's no question.

Comment: If your player's decoder knows to skip the priming sample, then 3.0s else 3.022s

Comment: Huh. So with MOV I can use PCM and avoid the ambiguity. But with other containers, like MP4, I don't think they accept PCM. Is there a way to avoid the ambiguity there?

Comment: Output to MOV with PCM and use mp4box to remux.